# How to undo silent mode on Nexus 4

Tags: nexus-4, volume-control

On the Nexus 4, I can silence the ringer by pushing the volume down button, however, when I push the volume up button, the ringer remains on silence until I go to settings and change the volume bar in ringtones. Shouldnt the volume up button work? Any suggestions?

Comment: There are any number of volume-control widgets in the Play Store. Will one of them not serve?

Comment: Does your volume up button work at all?

Answer (score 2):

That's odd - mine behaves the way you want:  pressing volume down decreases the volume, and then goes into vibrate and finally silent mode; then pressing volume up reverses all of this.

My Nexus 4 has the current version of Android: 4.3 (JWR66Y) on it.

Answer (score -1):

I have looked, but it seems there is nothing that will work with the volume up button to undo the silence.

Comment: Al, yes, my volume up button does work otherwise.

Comment: Tom, that is exactly what I want but my volume up button does not work to bring back the silence mode. I have to go into settings to do that. I am also on ver 4.3.